# Google actions approved/deployed

Tags: actions-on-google

My action has been approved/deployed. Release environment are labeled "Production".

However, it can not be invoked by Google Assistant users. The only way to invoke it, is on my own andriod-phone. But I am only getting the test-version.  (the action is in Norwegian language).

Answer (score 3):

It typically takes several hours for an Action to be fully deployed in production. The Actions console will change the release status from deploying to deployed once that is complete.

For you own developer account, you can either change the active version to the production version or you can disable testing on device by using the options at the top of the Actions console simulator page.

Answer (score 0):

It takes several hours for your action to get deployed until then it will only show as deploying, once it gets deployed you can use your actions on other phones.